# Jquery autocomplete with virtual keyboard

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use autocomplete with virtual keyboard (from http://keith-wood.name/keypad.html)

If i use the actual keyboard, autocomplete works but if i use the virtual keyboard by pressing with mouse autocomplete does not work. (On both cases virtual keyboard gets displayed perfect.)

How can i sort this out?

```
<style type="text/css">
@import "keyboard/jquery.keypad.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="keyboard/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function lookup(inputString) {
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            // Hide the suggestion box.
            $('#suggestions').hide();
        } else {
            $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    } // lookup

    function fill(thisValue) {
        $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="keyboard/jquery.keypad.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

$('#inputString').keypad();

});
</script>
</head>

<body>


    <div>
        <form>
            <div>
                Type your search:
                <br />
                <input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
            </div>

            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
                <img src="upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;" alt="upArrow" />
                <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onKeypress` callback function to run your lookup function after each keypress on the keypad.

```
$('#inputString').keypad({
    onKeypress: function(key, value, inst) { 
         lookup(value);
    } 
});
```

Comment: @baris22 what is causing it not to work? are you getting an error? did you try to even do a simple alert in the onKeypress callback? If onKeypress isn't working then there is a problem with either the way you are implementing the plugin or the plugin itself. Also just to make it clear, onKeypress is a custom event in the plugin that is called after each key clicked in the keypad, not an event on the input box.

Comment: I have got a small problem now. say the word is 12345 and when i type 1 auto complete comes for 0.5 seconds and goes away. when i type 2 same thing happens. When i press the back button on virtual keyboard auto complete comes back and stays there. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: `code` $(function () { $('#inputString').keypad({ onKeypress: function() { lookup(this.value); } }); }); function lookup(inputString) { if(inputString.length == 0) { // Hide the suggestion box. $('#suggestions').hide(); } else { $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){ if(data.length >0) { $('#suggestions').show(); $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data); } }); } } // lookup function fill(thisValue) { $('#inputString').val(thisValue); setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200); } `code`